# Select items from a list using wildcards

Tags: mysql, sql, select, concatenation

I have an `orders` table with a number of `items` related to each order:

```
id   | ... |  items
-----+-----+-----------------
34   | ... |  823, 27, 1657
678  | ... |  957
2548 | ... |  92, 823
```

Field `orders.items` stores contents as comma-separated `id`'s text field. (I know the design is wrong and there should be a one-to-many table to link orders with items, but I didn't design it).

**I need to select orders based on the items they contain**:

```
SELECT id, items FROM orders
WHERE items LIKE IN (
    SELECT CONCAT('%',id,'%') FROM items
    WHERE wishlist = 0
```

but obviously it does not work because I can't use `LIKE` in a list of items obtained from `IN`.
However, that is what I would require because I would need to use `%` wildcards to find them.

How can I achieve that?

**EDIT**:

In this **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ffb8b/3/1)** there is an example of my code **returning 7 lines and missing 2 of them**, in which the `FIND_IN_LIST` function has the exact same effect on the results.

Comment: `order` is a reserved word in MySQL so, as written, this query would not work in any case. But fundamentally, your problem is one of normalization (or lack thereof). FIND_IN_SET will do what you want, but it's a poor substitute for a properly normalized database.

Comment: I chose the name "order" just for illustration purposes -- you are right, I did wrong choice. However is not the name I use in my project.

Comment: Do you always have 3 items in your string?

Comment: @Mihai no, that's just an example. Can be 1, can be 2, can be N...

Comment: Thats really hard,you need an explode function for mysql.I think you`ll be better off with normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.id, o.items 
FROM orders AS o
INNER JOIN items AS i ON FIND_IN_SET(i.id, REPLACE(o.items, ' ', ''))
WHERE i.wishlist = 0 AND i.cost = 44800;
```

Check this [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8120e/3)

**OUTPUT**

```
|  ID |      ITEMS |
|-----|------------|
| 154 |   375, 374 |
| 155 |        377 |
| 159 |        384 |
| 172 |        435 |
| 174 |        440 |
| 228 |   770, 769 |
| 229 |    775,841 |
| 230 |        777 |
| 528 | 1518, 1517 |
```

Comment: I actually get the same results as if I just used a regular `IN` and no `CONCAT`... the returned results are right, but there are results missing anyway; not all the results are being returned.

Comment: From your description of the issue this should work (except it will bring back one row per item, per order - easily fixed). Could you post up an SQL fiddle of the tables and a bit of test data that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @Kickstart As you can see in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ffb8b/3/1 both methods (mine and the proposed in this answer) return 7 rows, and 2 remain missing from the results.

Comment: @Jago - the reason this solution wasn't returning a couple of order rows was because there were random spaces after the commas in some of the comma separated lists of item ids. Remove the spaces (or to a replace as proposed here) and it brings the rows back.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, items FROM `order` WHERE id REGEXP REPLACE(items,',','|');
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0055/4)

Which makes it like this,basically an advanced version of LIKE,'|' is for or

```
select id, items FROM test WHERE id REGEXP '823|167|398';
```

Comment: I am not very sure of how to apply this `REGEXP REPLACE` function to my code... Could you please elaborate based on my code on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ffb8b/3/1 ?